# How much reputation do I need to create new tags on SO?

Tags: support, tags

How much reputation do I need to create new tags on SO?

I cannot find the help pages for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges <-- 1500.

Comment: What tag do you think they system needs? I mean, there are more than 36k of them already.

Comment: I would like to be able to add the (36k+1)th tag if I stumble upon one one of the other `MAX_INT+` tags not yet created.

Comment: Then keep plugging away, and gain rep.